# Unable to install Linux - Laptop has no CD/DVD drive and shows no Bios

Tags: linux-mint

My laptop Toshiba Satellite 300 Ubantu old ver 8.0, which I want update to Linux Mint 18.0. The problem is my lap has no CD/DVD drive nor Bios prompt shows to boot.  When Booting, for 1-minute nothing on screen then Linux would pop up.  it never shows Bios screen despite trying with repair people for last 3-years, tried all the way with Fs keys F2, F12, F10 and Fs all keys, and even it was opened once for hardware reset with short-circuiting one particular item.

Nw what i propose or ask advise is :
I have LinuxMint 18.0 ISO in USB Drive. 
I would remove the hard disk from my Lap, and connect it another computer with usb cable as ext HDD, then burn LinuxMint 18.0 ISO file thru universal usb installer, then reconnect this Hard disk to my old computer and boot. Pls advise how to do it and whether it will work?

appreciate any assistance becuase last 3-yeras suffering this problem.

Comment: at boot do you see ubuntu's grub menu ?

Comment: the way you are talking about is dirty , you'll have problems with drivers!

Comment: Before you start your Laptop push F2 button with pushed F2 start laptop and let F2 pushed.  If you get acess to your Bios, look for an entry boot speed and change it to normal. I'm not sure if it works with your toshiba, so i write it as comment.

Comment: Try F12 to get the boot priority menu.

Comment: I had the same problem, tried all (almost) combinations of keys and restarts. Holding the F2 key before power button did the trick for me! Thanks